# Detail in proof $(A \cup B)'=A'\cup B'$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Given $A\subset X%$, denote by $A'$ be the set of all limit points of $A$ in $X$.

Now, I know several ways to prove that $(A\cup B)'=A'\cup B'$ which I'm perfectly happy with, but I came across the following and I cannot decide whether its correct or not:

(What follows concerns that $(A\cup B)'\subset A'\cup B'$, the other inclusion is quite trivial):

Let $x\in(A\cup B)'$, denote by $N_{\epsilon}(x)$ the neighbourhood of radius $\epsilon$ of $x$, then by definition of a limit point:

$$(\forall \epsilon>0)((N_{\epsilon}(x) \cap(A\cup B))-\left \{ x \right \}\neq\varnothing)$$

By De Morgan Laws:

$$(\forall \epsilon>0)((N_{\epsilon}(x) \cap A)-\left \{ x \right \}\neq\varnothing \vee (N_{\epsilon}(x) \cap B)-\left \{ x \right \}\neq\varnothing)  $$
Hence: 
$$x\in A' \vee x\in B'$$

My problem is going from the second line to the third, I'm not sure whether its actually valid or not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apologies, Reveillark, for my "misfire!"

Comment: You are correct in observing that the third line is not a legitimate consequence of the second. You could have e.g. that $N_{\epsilon}(x)\cap A -\{x\}$ is not empty if $\epsilon$ is rational and $N_{\epsilon}(x)\cap B -\{x\}$ is not empty if $\epsilon$ is not rational. For the third line you must know something more: $\delta<\epsilon\Rightarrow N_{\delta}(x)\subset N_{\epsilon}(x)$

Comment: Oh ok I think I get it. With the particular case you name I would need the inclusion property regarding neighbourhoods to go from the second line to the third, if I "didn't know" that, I wouldn't be able to. 
Thank you very much, if you want to copy and paste your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in observing that the third line is not a legitimate
consequence of the second.

You could have e.g. that $\left(N_{\epsilon}\left(x\right)\cap A\right)-\left\{ x\right\} \neq\emptyset$
if $\epsilon>0$ is rational and $\left(N_{\epsilon}\left(x\right)\cap B\right)-\left\{ x\right\} \neq\emptyset$
if $\epsilon>0$ is not rational.

You can only arrive at the third
line if you know more about the character of the sets $N_{\epsilon}\left(x\right)$.

The information $\delta<\epsilon\Rightarrow N_{\delta}\left(x\right)\subset N_{\epsilon}\left(x\right)$
is crucial.