# How's this for a simple proof of $(A \cup B)' = A' \cup B'$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to learn to do proofs in simple ways - by simple, irresistible statements rather than lengthy details.

I am wanting to prove that $(A \cup B)' = A' \cup B'$ provided that $A$ and $B$ are metric spaces.

An example of a lengthy detailed proof is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149469/detail-in-proof-a-cup-b-a-cup-b).

But here goes my (attempt at a) simple proof:

**PROOF**: $(A \cup B)'$ are all the limits points of sets $A$ and $B$.  $A' \cup B'$ are also all the limit points of sets $A$ and $B$.  QED.

So does the **PROOF** above work?  I suppose I could just quote a theorem to be simple, but I'm trying to make one-sentence proofs.

[Detail in proof $(A \cup B)'=A'\cup B'$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149469/detail-in-proof-a-cup-b-a-cup-b)

Answer (score 4):

I think you're brushing over important details using imprecise terminology. What does the limit points of two sets actually mean? Are you taking the individual limit points of each set individually, and grouping them together (i.e. $A' \cup B'$)? Or are you first mashing the sets together, and seeing what limit points this new set has (i.e. $(A \cup B)'$)?

Your argument seems to want the same term to mean both at the same time, which is assuming the conclusion before you've proven it. The argument can be paraphrased as "Well, I gave the two sets the same name, so they must be equal!".

Comment: Point(s) taken.  Thanks for your input Theo!

Answer (score 3):

I would say by most standards, this is not a sufficient proof, though I sympathize with the desire for short, succinct arguments. The issue with this proof is that you are merely asserting the two sets are equal by equating them each with "all the limit points of $A$ and $B$," but until you make that notion precise and show clearly how both sets in question are equal to "all the limit points of $A$ and $B$," it is not a finished proof.

As a side note, I would say that it is best to strive for clarity, rather than brevity. Sometimes the shortest arguments are hardly intelligible, while a long argument, if written well, can make the most demanding propositions crystal clear.

Comment: Point(s) taken, thanks Alex!

Answer (score 1):

No, if $A$ and $B$ are open sets, the set of all limit points of $A$ and $B$ is not $A \cup B$, since $A \cup B$ is open...

For example, if $A = (0,1)$ and $B$ is $(1,2)$, the set of all limit points of $A$ and $B$ if $[0,2] \ne A \cup B$.

Did you perhaps mean $(A \cap B)' = A' \cup B'$?

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by your answer. The question is to show that $(A\cup B)' = A'\cup B'$. Why are you bringing up $A\cup B$? As an aside, sometimes the set of all limit points of $A$ and $B$ is $A\cup B$, for instance when $A = B = \text{the whole space}$.

Comment: @gt6989b - You may be correct - maybe I should have put $(A \cap B)' = A' \cup B'$.  However, (unless I'm seriously mistaken), I never said that the set of all limit points of $A$ and $B$ was $A \cup B$.  I said is was $(A \cup B)'$.  Oh and by the way I'm fairly new to topology and metric spaces, so I could be stupid wrong about everything.  Simply put, this sentence is wrong!